How do one install UUID in the terminal of Visual Studio Code
I'm trying to install a UUID and link it to my js file so I can be able to generate unique user IDs whenever I want
I was already doing my project in Visual Studio Code, so I opened the terminal and typed: yarn add UUID. I expected it to install the UUID but it didn't. Rather, it said the term yarn is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program.
